# Does cytoscape.js have a way of producing JSON to be sent to server for saving?

Tags: cytoscape.js

There is a note on the cytoscape.js website that says:

"Note that a collection is immutible by default, meaning that the set of elements within a collection can not be changed. The API returns a new collection with different elements when necessary, instead of mutating the existing collection. This allows the developer to safely use set theory operations on collections, use collections functionally, and so on."

Does this mean it is not really suitable to use in the creation of online 'network editor' ie. where the user can interact to add and delete nodes and edges to the existing graph?

If I understand the note above it would mean that adding a new node would mean reconstructing the whole graph from scratch (but with the new node) and then presumably performing a complete redraw. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

A collection is a set of elements; the set merely points to all the individual elements.  You can think of it like an array of elements: The array just holds the elements.  Different arrays/sets can have different, similar, overlapping elements, etc.

Cytoscape.js is very suitable for the purpose you mention.  There are already projects that have live, collaborative editors (similar to google docs, online office, etc but for graphs).  For example, a simple one that I created is codenamed ["Factoid"](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/factoid) for biological processes.  Though I really think it ought to have a better, more accurate name -- you can still look through the code for a live collaboration example with Cytoscape.js.  Because you can listen to events easily, it's relatively straightforward to send diffs (or even just events) back and forth between the server and the client.

Adding an element is inexpensive: It just adds the single element and redraws if opportune.  It's even cheaper with `cy.batch()` for modifying lots of elements in a row.